# Can I (UK citizen) enter the US if I stop over for 14 days in the Caribbean?

Tags: usa, uk, covid-19, travel-ban

The [US travel ban](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html) says:

> foreign nationals who have been in any of the following countries during the past 14 days may not enter the United States.

and then goes on to list Schengen, UK, Brazil, China, Brazil, Iran.

However, the [Caribbean](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/06/12/which-countries-are-open-for-summer-travel-after-coronavirus.html) is opening back up to both US and UK tourists starting 1 July, including Puerto Rico.

Could I not just go to the Caribbean for 14 days, chill on the beach, and then enter the US? I had a big US road trip planned this summer and don't want to give up on it!

Comment: Puerto Rico is part of the US and has the same entry restrictions as the continental US.

Comment: In this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157770/my-girlfriend-lives-in-the-uk-and-i-want-to-be-able-to-come-and-leave-as-i-pleas you say you are a US citizen

Comment: @user253751 I just talked to the US state department and they said she can't come in even after a 14-day stopover in Bermuda

Comment: @Traveller Yes I am but my girlfriend is not and that's what I'm asking about. I just wanted to make the question as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

The [document issues by the Whitehouse explaining the ban](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-coronavirus-2/) states:

> The entry into the United States, as immigrants or nonimmigrants, of all aliens who were physically present within the United Kingdom, excluding overseas territories outside of Europe, or the Republic of Ireland **during the 14-day period preceding their entry or attempted entry into the United States is hereby suspended and limited subject to section 2 of this proclamation.**

You haven't been to the UK in the past 14 days before your attempted entry so that's fine.

Comment: Just realize that the USA can and has changed who can enter based on what happens with COVID 19.

Comment: @Willeke What do you mean?

Comment: If there are COVID 19 cases on the island you happen to be, or sometimes just somewhere in the region, the USA can change the rules and lock you out because of that.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, that can be the case

Comment: Also be aware that depending on where in the US you're going, you may be required to quarantine for a further 14 days after arriving. This rule is still in effect in a number of states.