# Why did the US department of state tell me UK citizen cannot enter the US after 15-day Carribean stopover?

Tags: usa, uk, covid-19, bermuda

I asked [before](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157757/can-i-uk-citizen-enter-the-us-if-i-stop-over-for-14-days-in-the-caribbean) whether UK citizen can enter after 15-day stopover in Bermuda and the answer seemed to be "yes." I have some critical new information that I believe justified a follow-up question.

I just spoke with the US government (US Citizens Crisis Assistance from travel.state.gov) and someone there told me this is not possible, that only US citizens and lawful permanent residents are allowed to enter the US, even after having been out for 14 days.

But [the government website](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html) seems pretty clear:

> **foreign nationals who have been in any of the following countries
> during the past 14 days may not enter the United States**

It does not say anything about foreign nationals who have not been in those countries during the past 14 days. Surely it would be easier for them to just say "no foreign nationals, at all"? Why enumerate the 14 day rule if the reality is different?

I have received contradictory information and was wondering if anyone here could help clear it up.

Maybe there is confusion on their end between the "no new visas" and the "no foreigners who've been in Europe/China/Iran/Brazil in past 14 days" rules? The UK citizen in question is not attempting to permanently immigrate for any reason–and already has an ESTA from September 2019 (valid for 2yrs).

**Edit** I think this question is just different enough due to how interesting it is that I was told seemingly contradictory information to many official online US government sources. The old question was already edited and full of comments. I apologize to anyone whose time I may have wasted.

**Second edit** I re-worded the question to stress that my question is about the contradiction between advice received from the US State Department Crisis Hotline (+1(202) 501-4444) and official advice. Please, stop trying to close this question as there is still lively truth-seeking going on.

**Final edit** I called Customs and Border Protection and they said the 14-day rule is the law. They also said they have no idea why the state department said what they did.

Comment: No idea what-so-ever why they said that. I am pretty confident the answer I provided (yes) is correct. Did they link to an official document where it says this is not possible?

Comment: @Daniil Yes. They directed me to this: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/Proclamation-Suspending-Entry-of-Immigrants-Who-Present-Risk-to-the-US-labor-market.html
Which just cites the proclamataion: https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspending-entry-immigrants-present-risk-u-s-labor-market-economic-recovery-following-covid-19-outbreak/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I (UK citizen) enter the US if I stop over for 14 days in the Caribbean?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157757/can-i-uk-citizen-enter-the-us-if-i-stop-over-for-14-days-in-the-caribbean)

Comment: Hi Derek, you should edit your existing question with the new information rather than asking a new question.

Comment: Do you have a US visa (and what type?) or are you trying to enter under VWP/ESTA?

Comment: Rather than simply close as a duplicate, I'm thinking this question could be usefully changed to specifically focus on "What is the practical impact on travel of the US presidential proclamation of April 22, 2020?"

Comment: @krubo Absolutely. I would love to see a comprehensive summary of that.

Comment: The US State Department is notorious for giving out bad information. I wouldn't recommend asking them much of anything if you can find a more reliable source.

Comment: In light of your final edit, could you either [accept](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer or [post your own](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accept that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea why the Department of State gave you that answer, but you were asking the wrong people.  It's rather as though you called your local fire department's fire safety inspector to find out whether you can get a license from the health department to operate a fruit stand.  They really shouldn't have given you *any* answer at all:

1. The office of US Citizens' Crisis Assistance is not concerned with entry requirements.  Its job to help US citizens, but the question you're trying to answer concerns only people who are not US citizens.
2. The Department of State does not operate immigration control at ports of entry; that is the responsibility of the Department of Homeland Security.  While the State Department does issue visas, its employees are not necessarily trained on the terms of the Visa Waiver Program, and even for travelers with visas the final decision lies with Customs and Border Protection, an agency of DHS.

Try calling an office of Customs and Border Protection.  They are the ones who actually decide whether someone can enter the US.  Their [contact page](https://www.cbp.gov/contact) links to a [map](https://www.cbp.gov/contact/ports) allowing you to locate ports of entry by state.

Answer (score 4):

The ESTA FAQ seems to confirm that after a stay of 14 days in Bermuda ('United Kingdom, **excluding overseas territories outside of Europe**,'), a holder of a valid ESTA may enter the United States.

> **What if I am a passport holder of a Schengen country with a valid ESTA but I have not been present in a Schengen country within 14 days of my travel to the United States?**
> Travelers are subject to the Proclamation if they were physically present within the Schengen Area during the 14-day period preceding their entry to the United States. This prohibition necessarily includes direct travel from, and transit through, the Schengen Area within the 14 day period.
>
> > If you have not been in the Schengen Area during the 14-day period preceding entry, and you are not departing from or transiting through the Schengen Area during your travel to the United States, then you are **not subject to the Proclamation**.
>
> **What if I am a British Citizen (GBR) and/or an Irish passport holder with a valid ESTA but I have not been present in a Schengen country within 14 days of my travel to the United States?**
> Travelers are now subject to the March 14, 2020 Proclamation if they were physically present within the United Kingdom, excluding overseas territories outside of Europe, or the Republic of Ireland during the 14-day period preceding their entry to the United States. This prohibition necessarily includes direct travel from, and transit through, the United Kingdom, excluding overseas territories outside of Europe, or the Republic of Ireland within the 14 day period.
>
> > If you have not been in the United Kingdom, excluding overseas territories outside of Europe, or the Republic of Ireland during the 14-day period preceding entry, and you are not departing from or transiting through the United Kingdom, excluding overseas territories outside of Europe, or the Republic of Ireland during your travel to the United States, then you are **not subject to the March 14, 2020 Proclamation**. However, you may be subject to Proclamation 9993 applicable to the Schengen Area if you have been physically present in the Schengen Area within 14 days of travel to the United States.

---

**Sources**:

- [Official ESTA Application Website, U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/faq?focusedTopic=Schengen%20Travel%20Proclamation)

Answer (score 1):

I am almost certainly sure that the *US Citizens Distress Hotline* was confused, either with the question you asked or were unsure of the information themselves.

The [US Government page](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html) clearly states traveling from these countries is possible after not being there for 14 days:

> **After arriving to the United States from one of these countries, CDC recommends that travelers stay home and monitor their health for 14 days.**

This clearly shows that passengers who have been in these countries (more than 14 days ago) are still allowed.

I have a feeling that the *US Citizens Distress Hotline* was confused with the rules for people who are exempt from this 14-day rule. The exemptions are published under *section 2* [here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-coronavirus-2/).

Comment: Just called again and they doubled down

Comment: @DerekFulton very strange, did you tell them about the document I linked to?

Comment: Yes. They told me that the March proclamation (https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-coronavirus-2/) allows for the 15-day Caribbean plan, but that there was an additional proclamation (https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspending-entry-immigrants-present-risk-u-s-labor-market-economic-recovery-following-covid-19-outbreak/) which bans entry of aliens entirely, and was apparently extended over the weekend to July 21.

Comment: @DerekFulton see my updated answer

Comment: I don't think this April 22, 2020 proclamation is relevant to OP's question, nor does it disallow most alien entry. The key phrase **as immigrants** in section 1 means that this proclamation only applies to people trying to immigrate to the US. I think OP is not asking about immigrating, but entering as a tourist or other short-term non-immigrant category.

Comment: @Daniil Weird how this second new proclamation wasn't in the news. I think the current assumption is the 14-day rule. We had good reason to believe that given the main proclamation and the CDC website.

Comment: @DerekFulton By chance, this second proclamation has just been meantioned in this BBC report: [Trump targets foreign workers with new visa freeze](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-53145317) **The White House first announced it was halting those visas in April, an order that had been set to expire on Monday.**

Comment: @MarkJohnson Could have sworn I told them on the phone she isn't trying to get a visa. She already has an ESTA from Sep 2019 (valid 2yrs). Might try again and stress that fact, but pretty sure they said no matter what. But have called three times so far. Their number is +12025014444.

Comment: Again, https://canitravel.net/ says 14-day rule.

Comment: @DerekFulton The ESTA FAQ answers this question directly, that after a 14 day stay in Bermuda an entry is possible.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I think the people I called were confused. Also, would like to add that the UK citizen in question **does** have a nonimmigrant visa (exception 2.ii)

Comment: @DerekFulton That would probably be a B1/B2 Visa, which is basically has the same conditions as an ESTA.

Comment: @krubo is correct.  Someone entering on the visa waiver program is a nonimmigrant, not an immigrant, and the proclamation you've quoted concerns only immigrants.  It does not apply to VWP travelers.

Comment: @phoog I have reverted back to the previous revision. Does it look right now?

Comment: @DerekFulton I'm pinging you here to make sure you're aware that the second proclamation applies only to *immigrants.* The new proclamation mentioned by Mark Johnson applies to some nonimmigrants (in addition to extending the general ban on immigrants), but only to certain work visas, so it is also irrelevant to a VWP visitor. (You mention in the question that she has an ESTA, which is explicitly *not* a visa under US law, but regardless, she's not subject to those proclamations.)  Daniil yes, the answer is much better now.